# Haskell socket programming - Memory leaks

Tags: networking, haskell, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, lazy-evaluation

I'm playing with some basic haskell network stuff but there is a problem
which drives me nuts. The following quite simple server code seems to leak
memory and I just don't know why.

First I fork the accept-method and just echo all incoming messages. I've tested
the server with the Apache Benchmark Tool ab. But after a few tests using ab the server 
process starts to leak memory, not much but continuously. I would guess roughly 1 MB every
10000 requests.

The question is: Is this some kind of internal Garbage Collector optimization or does it indeed
leak memory ? I've tested the program up to 200 MB memory usage, still growing.

In this example I'm using strict ByteStrings. Another test I did was using handle-based IO, which didn't caused the memory to grow over 3 MB in total.

Using lazy IO (ByteString.Lazy) caused the same problem but even faster.
I'm using GHC 7.6 (Windows 8).

```
echoClient :: Socket -> IO ()
echoClient nextSock = do
    -- Get a stream of bytes
    stream <- NetStrictBS.recv nextSock 120

    -- Echo back
    NetStrictBS.send nextSock stream

    -- Kill the socket
    sClose nextSock


acceptClients :: Socket -> IO ()
acceptClients sock = do

    -- Start with zero index
    loop sock 0
        where

        loop sock sockId = do
            -- Accept socket
            (nextSock, addr) <- accept sock

            -- Disable Nagle
            setSocketOption nextSock NoDelay 1

            -- Process client
            echoClient nextSock

            -- Accept next client
            loop sock (sockId + 1)


main = withSocketsDo $ do

    -- Setup server socket
    sock <- tcpSock
    setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
    bindSocket sock (SockAddrInet 1337 iNADDR_ANY)
    listen sock 128

    -- Fork the acceptor
    forkIO $ acceptClients sock

    print "Server running ... " >> getLine >>= print
```

Comment: ghc version and version of the network package?

Comment: GHC 7.6, as I mentioned above. Network package 2.4.1.2 (the latest)

Comment: a small tip, read http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simple_Servers and this http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Implement_a_chat_server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just spoke to an colleague and he told me that the problem is this section

```
loop sock (sockId + 1)
```

I'm buildung up thunks without ever evaluting, which definitely fills up the heap.
I hope this helps other people facing similiar problems.

Comment: Yep, `sockId` is never used, so the compiler sees no reason to evaluate `sockId + 1`.

Comment: Theoretically, the compiler should not even generate the thunk itself when it finds that it is not used ;)

Comment: did you compile with optimizations on?

Comment: I did compile with -O2. Are there any other useful optimization flags?

Comment: @Kr0e no that's what I meant. It's surprising to me that GHC didn't make that go away!